# How to use LED lighting strip on ceiling?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

In our living room, we have a single ceiling rose in the centre of the ceiling with a boring light fitting on it.  I'd love to replace this with 4 led strips (about 2m each) running from the centre to the corners, ideally of the colour-changing sort.

My question is how can I fit this in a way that looks ok and is safe?  I'd ideally like a circular thingy where the light fitting is, that contains the transformer and colour controller, and has the light strips coming out of it, but I can't find any such thing on the internet.  Is my quest doomed to failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I doubt you'll find anything built and marketed as exactly what you are asking for, you can certainly find suitable electrical boxes to connect and contain things safely, and then do what you need to satisfy an "appearance shroud" over them. Probably the best bet for the appearance shroud would be a simple light fixture (not to be lit - simply to cover "ugly" junction boxes)[image: round light]  [image: square light] [image: Exterior-type extension box][image: Interior-type extension box]